# Gfci Breaker with two circuits?

Tags: electrical, gfci

I’ve got a 30 amp breaker currently connected to my outside A/C condenser and I’m planning on adding a steam shower to the basement bathroom that requires a 20amp gfci breaker. There is a conjunction box mounted underneath my floor joists where a 220v circuit (from breaker) has a splice between the 10 gauge wire that joins another length of 10 gauge the remaining length outside to the condenser. What I wanted to do was connect another 220 V circuit in that box and run it over to the bath and upgrade to a gfci breaker using 10 gauge as well (steam shower requires 12).

Is this an okay solution? I would basically have A/C and steam shower running off one GFCI breaker, which I plan to upgrade to 50amp.

Comment: Running a 30 and 20 amp devices from one 50 amp is not good.  What is good is upgrading to the 50 amp breaker to power a sub panel from which you can have a 30 and amp breaker to power the AC and shower.  Will need 6 gauge wire/cable from the breaker to sub panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just add the circuit values together to put in a bigger breaker. That's a general rule, and there are certain very specific exceptions (e.g., with multiple cooking appliances).

But in any case you can't do this because **all of the wire** must be appropriate for the breaker size. The breaker protects the equipment but first and foremost it protects the wire. For a 50A breaker, the wire needs to be either 6 AWG or 8 AWG, depending on wire/cable type. See an [ampacity table](https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/) for details. 10 AWG and 12 AWG are simply not allowed on a normal 50A circuit.

In addition, replace the 30A GFCI with a 50A GFCI is going to be as expensive, if not more expensive, than adding a 20A GFCI. If your steam shower is actually a 120V circuit then a 20A GFCI is much less expensive and doesn't even have to be a GFCI/breaker, which will save even more.

In any case, the correct solution is to add a new 20A 12 AWG circuit and not touch the 30A circuit.

Comment: Appreciate the help! I have a sub panel in my garage that I still have room to to add a breaker. Will install 20 amp double pole breaker and do a run with the correct wire size from there as it is roughly only 30 feet away and easily accessible.